# get list of sub-directories name present under directory

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark

i am very much new to scala and trying to fetch the sub-directories name ,present at particular path.

```
Directory path = "/src/test/output/"

Sub-directories present under Directory path are :20180101,20190302,19990409,20110402
```

I just need the sub-directories names as List in scala .

I have tried this

```
val result = new JFile(path).listFiles.map(_.getName).toList
```

But this is not working ,can anyone please help me ??

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more details about your problem, like compilation errors, error stacktraces etc.

Comment: i am getting blank : this is the output 

(List()) and not sure why it is giving like this

Answer (score 0):

You can check the examples from [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-list-files-in-directory-filter-names-scala).

```
def getListOfFiles(dir: String):List[String] = {
  val d = new File(dir)
  if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
    d.listFiles.filter(_.getName).toList
  } else {
    List[String]()
  }
}
```